# supersized fit_always ?

Tags: supersized

I have just set up supersized on my new site, with the intention of using it for the background. (not the slideshow)

How ever, i cant seem to get it to fit_always.
i am not sure if i am changing the right setting.

```
    /* Default Options
----------------------------*/
$.supersized.defaultOptions = {

    // Functionality
    start_slide             :   1,          // Start slide (0 is random)
    new_window              :   1,          // Image links open in new window/tab
    image_protect           :   1,          // Disables image dragging and right click with Javascript

    // Size & Position                         
    min_width               :   0,          // Min width allowed (in pixels)
    min_height              :   0,          // Min height allowed (in pixels)
    vertical_center         :   1,          // Vertically center background
    horizontal_center       :   1,          // Horizontally center background
    fit_always              :   0,          // Image will never exceed browser width or height (Ignores min. dimensions)
    fit_portrait            :   1,          // Portrait images will not exceed browser height
    fit_landscape           :   0,          // Landscape images will not exceed browser width

};
```

I have tried adjusting the 0 & 1 variables. but im not 100% sure this is the right place, as nothing seems to change. ??

I have also come across this [Fit_Always Website](http://devblog.labfiftyfive.com/supersized-jquery-plugin-fit-always-per-image/)

with this code

```
    {image : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/slides/wojno-1.jpg', fit_always: true}
```

So i even tried putting fit_always: true etc.. after the imgage link, but then the image just fails to load.

website is www.amberroom_salon.co.uk

thanks